# fingerprint reader or thumb reader

Tags: c#, java, fingerprint

I am wanting to develop an Automatic Attendance System using a thumb reader. When the user enters the office campus, they must put their thumb on to a thumb reader and is then marked as present.

Can anyone suggest a thumb reader that supports API for reading and comparing thumb-print images, so that I can easily integrate it with my attendance system.

I would prefer it if the device supports a Java API.

I have Google'd this a lot, but could not find any good answers.

I came across a Microsoft thumb reader,but i dint get enough information on it.
Does anyone can provide me offical site of Microsoft thumb reader.
Any online stiulator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I work in company developing such systems. We've successfully used devices by [Futronic](http://www.futronic-tech.com/), both USB (FS80) and ethernet (FS84). The latter provide means for comparison, but AFAIk they aren't very good.

We've used matching algorithms by [Sonda Technologies](http://sonda-tech.com/), they are very robust and have good performance. They provide JNI-style java API.

We've also used ethernet sensors by this company, it has better capabilities for indication (LED or text LCD display, and sound) and operating external devices.

Comment: USB scanners are good for users registration and ethernet ones good for checkpoints, since it's easy to deploy them - all you need is power supply and a place for twisted pair cable. Ethernet sensors have outputs for operating external device e.g. turnstiles.

SondaSDK allows to capture images, build fingerprint templates and compare them.

We've built a .NET wrapper around it and a set of high-level classes which makes building new biometrics apps simple. The search is parallel, so we can find a person in a base of ~5000 fingers in about 600ms. This is less than finger image capture time.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Does FS84 and FS80 better then microsoft thumb reader?Are they expensive compared to microsoft thumb reader?
does FS84 and Fs80 comes with SDK which can help to comare and search matches of fingerprints in db?Will FS84/FS80 /microsoft thum reader will be better for my attendance system.I intend to do the high level programing in java.Does it support java?Can u add me on live/yaoo/skype?
My contact details are mindegdes@yahoo.com and skype id is akshayshetye

Comment: Can i get a simulator of hardware on which i can test my code.