# open source SDK for fingerprint matching

Tags: java, fingerprint

I am looking for a opens source SDK in java for fingerprint matching with good accuracy.
Can anyone suggest me one?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576605/fingerprint-reader-or-thumb-reader

Comment: None of the suggested SDK in that question are open source.

Comment: @Kyle Rozendo: That's actually a question asked by the same person. The previous one was just about API, while this has a wider scope - SDK.

Comment: @quosoo: noone of the answers mentions abt a open src SDK there

Comment: As an aside - by 'Open Source' do you actually mean 'free'?  People often confuse the two distinct things.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this post is old, but I was just looking for a similar answer today and came across this post.  I have not used this SDK, but reading the documentation the API seems straight forward and simple to use.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sourceafis/index.php?title=SourceAFIS

Comment: This answer is not valid as link is broken

Comment: @Ravi link is not broken

Comment: Well, it's open source, but seems like it's in dotNet not Java, quiet the bummer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a SDK exists. Opensource and in Java?

Java is already not the best language for direct hardware access (thinking of the finger print readers). And you didn't mention which finger print reader it should be for.

If you want a SDK which is able to use multiple readers I suggest reading this answer to a similar question

[Is there a fingerprint reader api/sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277373/is-there-a-fingerprint-reader-api-sdk/277505#277505)

Comment: i am not looking for reader.i am looking for a sdk that wil help me in matching fingerprint.Normalyy the device wil provide the api for reading the sacnned fingerprint.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some (can't vouch for quality):

- [Biometric SDK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biometricsdk/)
- [Level 3 Fingerprint Image Toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/level3tk/)

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/biometricsdk/

this SDK is available for java and C++ (good for direct Hardware access).